# Javascript repeat a function x amount of times

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to develop a function that repeats a function x amount of times, just once, not based on `settimerinterval` or `settimeout` or anything based on time.  I don't want to use a while/for loop **directly**, I want to use this repeat function.

I've tried something like this:

```
function repeat(func, times) {
  for (x = 0; x < times; x++) {
    eval(func)
  }
}
```

But `eval` doesn't work on a function.

Comment: You don't want to use a loop or a `setTimeout`. How else can you call something `n` times? You're basically ruling out all the possibilities to complete your code. Why is a loop no good?

Comment: func is js function or string ? If function is string how it's defined ( there few ways to define function in js)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just call `func` and decrement counter and call the function `repeat` again.

```js
function repeat(func, times) {
    func();
    times && --times && repeat(func, times);
}

repeat(function () { document.write('Hi<br>'); }, 5);
```

Comment: Loops aren't allowed apparently... which is nonsense obvs.

Comment: depending on number, this might be a bad idea, since recursive call are limited : https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2009/05/19/javascript-stack-overflow-error/

Comment: @DiegoDupin, the above has an exit condition.

Answer (score 27):

```
const func = () => console.log("hi");
const times = 3;

Array.from({length: times}, () => func());
```

I define a function.
I set the number of times to repeat function.
I make an array the size of times to repeat function.
I run the "defined function" on each element of the array.

Comment: This is handy for generating an array of "x number of things"

Answer (score 1):

If Lodash is an option, then [_.times](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#times)

Answer (score 1):

You can also define a reusable function, utilizing `setInterval` and `clearInterval`

```
function runFunctionXTimes(callback, interval, repeatTimes) {
    let repeated = 0;
    const intervalTask = setInterval(doTask, interval)

    function doTask() {
        if ( repeated < repeatTimes ) {
            callback()
            repeated += 1
        } else {
            clearInterval(intervalTask)
        }
    }
} 

function sayHi() {
    console.log("Hi")
}
```

The following line will run `sayHi` 5 times without wasting any time between completion of one and the beginning of another.

```
runFunctionXTimes(sayHi, 0, 5)
```

It is also possible to pass function arguments to `setInerval`, you can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to eval() a function, but you can call it. Here's the fix:

```js
function repeat(func, times) {
  for (x = 0; x < times; x++) {
    func()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion:

```
function repeat(fn, times) {
  var loop = function (times) {
    if (times) {
      fn(times);
      loop(--times);
    }
  }
  loop(times);
}

repeat(function (times) {
  console.log(times);
}, 5);
```